# Upload gif images to the server without lossing animation using PHP

Tags: php, file-upload, gif, animated-gif

I have used image upload class for a PHP web application and it works fine with jpg and png. But when I upload gif images they loss their animation. If anybody has idea about this please guide me through.

Answer (score 3):

`move_uploaded_file` function work with `gif` without issues..

You can try this code,

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $_FILES['file']['name']);
}
?>


<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file"name="file"/>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @user3099298